# Default Button on Form (VB 2008)

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I want to find a way to make a specific button, the form's default button, 
I.e. the button that is highlighted when the form opens for the first time.

I tried the AcceptButton property but when I run the program, that does not work.

Any idea?

Thank you in advance,

Tassos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The form's `AcceptButton` and `CancelButton` properties define the default behaviour for the Enter and Escape keys, rather than the highlighting.

To highlight the button use the Focus method, but when doing this in the form_load event you will need to call the Select method instead.

```
btnDefault.Select()
```

As mentioned in the comments, setting the control to the lowest taborder will achieve the same thing

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

But i tried that and nothing changed. What is wrong with it?

Comment: Use Select(), Focus can only work when the button is visible.  Which it isn't yet in the Load event.  Even simpler is to just give the button the lowest TabIndex.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant my WinForms is a bit rusty.  I've updated the answer;

Answer (score 7):

You need to change the `AcceptButton` property of the containing form.

```
form1.AcceptButton = button1
```

Here `form1` is the Form whose default button you need to set, and `button1` is the name of the Button on that form.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from 'chk' on 5/2/13 is the correct answer, but is shown as a string which of course is not the way to do it.

Also, in the form's property sheet you can find, under Misc, the property 'AcceptButton'.  This will give you a list of buttons on the form - just select the one you want.

The button selected as the AcceptButton will behave as the 'default' button.  It will be 'highlighted' with a darker border and will be clicked when you push the Enter key on your keyboard.

Setting up an AcceptButton is different than setting the button's focus.  The AcceptButton's click event will be triggered by the Enter key no matter which control has the focus on the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this programmatically.
I have a maintenance form where initially I want the "search" button as the form accept button.
when I'm displaying the field maintenance area, I want the "ok" button to be the accept button.
You simply change this in the appropriate areas in your code to Me.AcceptButton = *MyButtonName*.

Answer (score 0):

Under vs2022, you can simply set the AcceptButton property in the property sheet.  You will get a list of all buttons (regular ones as well as the installed FontAwesome buttons) to choose from.